# Remove line break from bottom of Web Intelligence report

Tags: business-objects

I have a BusinessObjects Web Intelligence report that feeds data in to a program to interface between two software applications. That said, the data needs to be in a precise format for the program to accept it.

The BO report is saved as a text file (.txt) before being dropped in. Since upgrading to Webi 4.1, an issue which is causing a rejection has occurred. At the bottom of the report, two blank lines are generated in the .txt file, which aren't visible in the Webi application. The footer has been hidden and borders removed from the data block. When the report is saved as an .xls, it has a row beneath it which is enlarged and filled white.

It appears that there is a margin imposed on the data block, but I cannot find any formatting setting to edit this.*
The image below displays the issue:

[image]

I have to manually remove these line breaks each time I run this report, which has taken away the full automation achieved with the previous version of BusinessObjects (Deski).

Anybody know if it is possible to solve this, and where the setting can be found in the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a known bug and is described in SAP KB note [2143332](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/2143332) - *Text (.txt) output of a Web Intelligence report generates two blank lines at the bottom of the table*.

The bug is solved in SAP BusinessObjects BI 4.1 SP06, which is not yet released. The release of SP06 is planned for week 24 (mid June), as indicated in the [SAP BusinessObjects maintenance schedule](https://service.sap.com/~sapidb/011000358700001430852011).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to open either of the links you have provided to verify this information.

Comment: Both links require a SAP Support account to log on. If you have an active maintenance contract, you should have an S-ID.